# Compare two numbers represented as linked list

Tags: java, performance, recursion, linked-list

I'm trying to solve a question where a whole, positive number is represented as a one way linked list where the least significant digit is the head node.

For example the number 1234 is represented as: 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> null

I'm trying to create a recursive algorithm, but I'm afraid I'm running into some trouble. I would appreciate if you could take a look and guide me in the right direction:

```java
public int compareTo(BigNumber other){
        String thisStr = toString();
        String otherStr = other.toString();
        if (thisStr.length() > otherStr.length())
            return 1;
        if (thisStr.length() < otherStr.length())
            return -1;
        if (thisStr.equals(otherStr))
            return 0;
        return compareTo(_head, other._head);
    }

    private int compareTo(IntNode ptr1, IntNode ptr2){
        int ret = 0;
        if (ptr1.getNext() != null && ptr2.getNext() != null)
            return compareTo(ptr1.getNext(), ptr2.getNext());

        if (ptr1.getValue() > ptr2.getValue())
            ret = 1;
        else if (ptr1.getValue() < ptr2.getValue())
            ret = -1;

        return ret;
    }
```

I'm having trouble with the case where the length is equal. I would like to create a recursion that first goes to the last node (The most significant digit), and checks backwards the nodes.

The issue is that the function *must* have a return value, and if the two values are equal, 0 is returned, no further iteration moves to the node before the last.

I'd love to hear your ideas, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line, you immediately return (based on the most significant digit only):

```
return compareTo(ptr1.getNext(), ptr2.getNext());
```

Instead, you must only return if the result is different to 0, otherwise check the next digit.

Comment: Brilliant, mate! Brilliant!